# custom menu in blackberry - change font color of menu item

Tags: blackberry, menuitem, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have created `custom menu` in my application, i have already set its `background,border and font` of the item display in the menu. But i could not able to set `font color` for the menu item display in menu.
How to set font color for the menu item??..
my code look like this :
I have set border,background and font as shown below :-

```
XYEdges edge = new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10);
menu_border = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(edge,Border.STYLE_DOTTED);
menu_back = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.LIGHTPINK,50);
    try 
    {
        FontFamily fnt_family = FontFamily.forName("BBCasual");
        menu_font = fnt_family.getFont(Font.PLAIN,30,Ui.UNITS_px);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    }
```

and i override the makeMenu() function as shown:

```
protected void  makeMenu(Menu menu,int context) 
{
    menu.setBackground(menu_back);
    menu.setBorder(menu_border);
    menu.setFont(menu_font);
    super.makeMenu(menu, context);
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API to do what you want.

Comment: is there any other way to do this??

Answer (score -1):

```
LabelField label0=new LabelField(" Label",LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH){

     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {                                   
          g.setColor(Color.RED);
          super.paint(g);
     }   
};
```

This code set the font color of labelfield to red use it for menu and change the color as u want

Comment: This code can't be used neither for `Menu` nor for `MenuItem`.